# Resize equation/Aligning equation/

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am writing my thesis but some of the equation widths is more than the text width.for example

```
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq7}
\Theta(m+2)&=&\frac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)}\Bigg[N^2\,\Theta(m)-N^2\,\theta_{a}\delta(m)+
N_{r}\,\sum_{\ell=0}^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\phi(j)\phi(k-j)\phi(\ell-k)\phi(m-\ell)\nonumber\\&&
-PeS\sum_{\ell=0}^{m}\delta(\ell-1)(m-\ell+1)\Theta(m-\ell+1)-Pe\,(m+1)\,\Theta(m+1)-N_{r}\,\theta_{s}\,\delta(m)\Bigg].
\end{eqnarray}
```

What can I do to fit text width?

I try to write the equation fit to text width

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can actually fit the equation to the text width as it is very long. You may try by using a smaller font size but I doubt this will work.

I would actually suggest another approach by splitting the terms in different equations and bringing the whole thing as a much smaller equation. This obviously may not be possible depending on how you are able to write things.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}                      
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{eq7}
X_1 =& N^2\,\Theta(m)-N^2\,\theta_{a}\delta(m)+ N_{r}\sum_{\ell=0}^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\phi(j)\phi(k-j)\phi(\ell-k)\phi(m-\ell) \\
X_2 =& -PeS\sum_{\ell=0}^{m}\delta(\ell-1)(m-\ell+1)\Theta(m-\ell+1) \\
X_3 =& -Pe\,(m+1)\,\Theta(m+1)-N_{r}\,\theta_{s}\,\delta(m) \\
\Theta(m+2) =& \frac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)}\Bigg[X_1 + X_2 + X_3\Bigg]
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

I know this is not what you asked but I hope this may still help.

You may also want to try the `split` environment that comes within the `amsmath` or `mathtools` packages. It will allow you to manually break the equation in several lines but numbering the whole equation as only one.

Lastly,  [this document](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) provides an interesting discussion about the `eqnarray` environment being more destructive than useful for the document. The `align` environment should be prefered (when possible).

Clézard